# How can I find the default KDF for my version of GPG?

Tags: gnupg, kdf

I am trying to find the default KDF for my version of gpg:

- gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.6
- libgcrypt 1.8.2

Does anyone know how?

Comment: GnuPG uses S2K.

Comment: Hi Forest!  Could you tell me how you know that?  Thanks.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880#section-3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GnuPG uses an algorithm called S2K (String-to-Key). This isn't unique to GnuPG, and is actually part of the official OpenPGP standard, specifically [RFC 4880 § 3.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.7). The strongest version of this KDF, version 3, works by repeating the key and the salt many times and hashing the whole result.

The specific hash algorithm used is specified with [`--s2k-digest-algo`](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/r2059.html).